# Как исключить значение, которые отличаются от среднего на 2 отклонения и больше для категориальных признаков?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть DataFrame. В этом DataFrame есть 2 столбца:

1. Pclass - класс пассажира. В системе есть только 3 типа пассажиров: 1, 2, 3
2. Fare - стоимость билета

Мне необходимо:
Создать признак, который показывает отличается ли стоимость билета от сдернего значения больше чем на 2 стандартных отклонения для каждого из классов пассажиров. 
Если  стоимость билета отличается от среднего значения больше чем на 2 стандартных отклонения - такие значения с DataFrame надо исключить

Вот мой код:

```
def fare_group(Fare):
    for Pclass, Value in df.groupby('Pclass'):
    return 'yes' if abs(df['Fare']-Value['Fare'].mean())>2*Value['Fare'].std() else 'no'
df['fare_group'] = df['Fare'].apply(fare_group)
```

При выполнении этого кода, система выдает ошибку:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Что мне исправить и вообще верная ли логика заложена мною в коде для выполнения этой задачи?

Comment: Вы сообщение перевели?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets да )

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)